# Converting inches to centimetres

Tags: excel, excel-2003

I have a list of dimensions with the `"` symbol that I want to convert to cm.  For example:

```
104" X 110"
87" x 110"
78" x 80" x 15"
60" x 80" x 15"
```

Comment: show us what you've tried yet

Comment: I tried using the convert function but it's not working with the other characters in the cell

Comment: think about how you will find out if it is simple cm or sqaure cm or cubic cm

Comment: please give of the expected output behind the examples

Answer (score 3):

Replace `X` with `x` and `"` with nothing. Apply Text To Columns with `x` as delimiter. Enter 2.54 into a spare cell and copy that cell. Select all your data and Paste Special Multiply. Stitch results back together with concatenation (for the same format as input) or with multiplication to get areas/volumes.